# How can I stop a data-driven coded ui test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, data-driven-tests

Can anyone tell me how to stop iterating on first failure of a data-driven coded ui test?  I have hundreds of iterations and I want to know something failed before having it complete.  Meaning, I don't want to have to wait hours to know that the first iteration has failed.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: It would help to post some code...

Comment: there isn't really much code to post.  It is just a codedui test that pulls iterations out of MTM.  Assert will fail that iteration, just didn't know if there was a way to stop iterating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue and after some research I found that there are two possible solution:
1. *The complicated one* - create your own Test Dispatcher with your own custom data adapter by implementing **ITestMethodInvoker** interface. There you can run test iteration in the way you wish. You will also need to override **TestContex** class to feed your Test Method with DataRows from your data adapter.
2. *The simplest one* - this wont actually stop Visual Studio from iterating through all DataRows in your Data Source but instead of performing the actual test method, Visual Studio will mark it as skipped and move on. Here is the sample code:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class MyTestClass
{
    private TestContext testContext;
    private static int countFailedIterations = 0;
    private static string currentMethod = "";

    public MyTestClass()
    {
        if (!currentMethod.Equals(testContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName))
        {
            // Reset Iteration Count
            countFailedIterations = 0;
            currentMethod = testContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName;
        }
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void MyTestInit()
    {
        if (countFailedIterations > 0)
            Assert.Inconclusive("Stop it, please");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void MytestCleanup()
    {
        if (testContext.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
            countFailedIterations++;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("MyDataSource")]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        //Blah Blah Blah
    }

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return testContext; }
        set { testContext = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this... it is exactly what I was looking for.  I just tried it out, and it seems like my TestContext is null as soon as it gets to the constructor, so it never actually continues on into the TestMethod.  Am I missing something?

Comment: just removing the constructor actually worked... odd.  Oh well, this is what I needed.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The code inside constructor is required only if you have multiple data-driven test methods so you would like to reset failed iterations counter. But you're right - when the constructor runs the TestContext is still not initialized. You can actually move the code from the constructor to MyTestInit() method - it should work.